# Android 8 - KeyGenerator class generateKey() method crash the application

Tags: android, aes, android-keystore, key-generator

My app is getting crashed on Android 8 devices while executing the code `keyGenerator.generateKey()` method. Getting following error like as below.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to instantiate
> service com.abc.test.MService: java.security.ProviderException:
> Keystore operation failed
>
> android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey
> (AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:321)
> javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey (KeyGenerator.java:604)
> Caused by java.security.ProviderException Keystore operation failed
>
> android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException (KeyStore.java:709)
> javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey (KeyGenerator.java:604)

On other devices it is working fine. Can anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: We need more details in order to help you, Please provide some application code.